# Calendar.clone() Incorrectly copying milliseconds

Tags: java, android, calendar, gregorian-calendar

It doesn't seem that this question has come up before, so I'll ask it here: Is the expectation with the "shallow" copying of a Calendar via Calendar.clone() that the milliseconds stored become invalid?

I ask because the following chunk of code is failing:

```
public boolean someFunc(Calendar prevTime, Calendar proposal) {
    int submissionMinuteThreshold = 30;
    boolean isAfterMinTime;
    ...
    Calendar min = (GregorianCalendar) prevTime.clone();
    Log.i("PROJ", "1. Proposed time = " + proposal.getTimeInMillis() + ", min time = " + min.getTimeInMillis());
    min.add(Calendar.MINUTE, submissionMinuteThreshold);
    Log.i("PROJ", "2. Proposed time = " + proposal.getTimeInMillis() + ", min time = " + min.getTimeInMillis());
    isAfterMinTime = proposal.after(min); // returns true even though min is 29 minutes later
```

I've experimented with the following settings:
`proposal` = 10:34 AM on 2014-10-25
`prevTime` = 10:33 AM on 2014-10-25

Log output is shown below:

1. Proposed time = 1414247640000, min time = -61180824420000
2. Proposed time = 1414247640000, min time = -61180822620000

After looking through the fields of `min` in the debugger, I see that `add` correctly sets the hour to 11, minutes to 03, and date to 2014-10-25, so it seems that `add` works correctly. However, when the comparison is performed, the milliseconds set in `min` are completely wrong, and that's what `after` (in the `Calendar` class) uses for a comparison.

As can be seen in the log output, the root of the problem with the milliseconds stored seems to begin with `Calendar min = (GregorianCalendar) prevTime.clone()`. Is there some other copy method that I should use so as to ensure valid comparisons later?

Comment: What happens if you skip the clone, create a calendar and set its values manually via set()? If that works then the problem is either from clone() or prevTime itself.

Comment: Of course it comes down to user error... In one case where I constructed prevTime -- the case that manifested above -- I accidentally used the day of the month in place of the year. I happened to overlook that pretty crucial point when scanning through the Calendar fields in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect initialization of prevTime, as suggested by prettyvoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding min.getTime() just before the proposal.after(min), and see it work ;) .. I will leave it to you to read the source code and figure out why.